# revert back all number to its original place

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the attach file i have some sequence number row 1-18694753 row 2-85354713 so on...

I have many rows, it reaches 800 rows with different numbers each in column A

Is there a way to save the position of the number in each row?

I wanted to sort it first from smallest into highest number then edit something on column B and then after i edit I wanted to revert back all rows to original places

Sample: I wanted to revert back row 1-18694753 row 2-85354713 to the original place after i sorted it from lowest into highest

hope someone may help me

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this vial excel formula, at least I don't know one. You could do some wonky stuff with some helper columns/ helper sheets tht save the position of every entry, but that does not seem like it would be robust. I would suggest VBA

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. There is no attached file... could you upload your data and your expected output? The description is not very clear.

Comment: How is your data currently sorted, if at all? If it is currently sorted in a set way, the way to revert to your original sorting is to just reapply this sorting. If it isn't sorted, you could do what @M.Schalk suggest, and use a helper column. With your original sorting, number each row from 1 to how many you need, then sort from smallest to largest to undo your previous sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish it by inserting an additional column. I am attaching the screenshots for your ready reference. For brevity, I am using only ten rows.

[image]

**Explanation:**

*First segment:*

1. Contains three columns: a) Serial Number, b) sequence number, and c) Description
2. The serial number is populated using *Fill | Series* method

*Second segment:*

1. Sequence number sorted in ascending series. You will see that the serial number (the first column of the second segment)  is not in order.

*Third Segment:*

1. Sorting the data by serial number restores to its old position.